# How to design for mobiles with Shopify Store

Tags: css, mobile, media-queries, shopify

I am currently trying to write some media queries to make my site responsive to other devices. I normally build my sites in Joomla and tend to use modules that are switched off using media queries and mobile modules that are switched on i.e. display: none, display: block..

With the Shopify store that I have built using the Timber Framework, I am not sure if i can implement the same methods, although the timber framework is responsive there are some elements that are not sitting correctly.

For example I am currently trying to sort my header layout for a mobile. Currently for the desktop I have a logo, contact button, search button and cart and this sits the way i need it.

```
<div class="grid--full grid--table">
<div class="grid__item large--one-quarter"></div>
<div class="grid__item large--one-quarter"></div>
<div class="grid__item large--one-quarter"></div>
<div class="grid__item large--one-quarter"></div>
</div>
```

Now if I wanted to change the code for a mobile to be:

```
<div class="grid--full grid--table">
    <div class="grid__item large--one-half"></div>
    <div class="grid__item large--one-half"></div>
</div>
```

I'm not sure how i would do this, as with using the "one-quarter" this works well on a desktop screen, but on a mobile it squeezes everything into separate lines and I need to show this on one line.

Hope that makes sense, if somebody could please advise would really appreciate it.